# Get longest strings in DB2 column

Tags: db2

I'm trying to get the longest strings in a given DB2 table. I know the max length of the columns from the schema, but I want to generate a report showing the longest actual values.

For example, if the table looked like

```
ID    NAME    EMAIL         SALARY
1234  Julio   j@myco.com    12345.00
1235  Sara    s@myco.net    23456.00
1236  Sid     sid@myco.net  452.00
```

How can I get the values

```
NAME    EMAIL        SALARY
Julio   sid@myco.net 23456.00
```

Note that I don't need the actual length of the longest values, I am interested in seeing the values themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    ,   MAX(LENGTH(EMAIL)) OVER() AS MAX_LEN
    FROM
        EMAIL_TABLE
)
WHERE LENGTH(EMAIL) = MAX_LENGTH
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems Yo want to get the longest result to each and every column (maybe for salary the highest). Try this:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT name FROM x ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) AS name,
    ( SELECT email FROM x ORDER BY LENGTH(email) DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) AS email,
    ( SELECT salary FROM x ORDER BY salary DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) AS salary
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Another alternative:

```
WITH ord_tbl AS
(
   SELECT name, email, salary,
         ROWNUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC) AS name_ord,
         ROWNUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LENGTH(email) DESC) AS email_ord,
         ROWNUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY salary DESC) AS salary_ord
     FROM x
)
SELECT MIN(DECODE(name_ord, 1, name)) AS name,
      MIN(DECODE(email_ord, 1, email)) AS email,
      MIN(DECODE(salary_ord, 1, salary)) AS salary
  FROM ord_tbl
```